# How to add 2 columns together in a call to update_counters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do this:

```
User.update_counters(user.id, :counter3 => :counter1 + :counter2)
```

But I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
User.update_counters(user.id, :counter3 => (user.counter1 + user.counter2))
```

this should work...

In your example you're trying to add two symbols (:counter1 + :counter2), but there's no +-method for symbols... and if it were you would set :counter3 to to the result of the addition of the symbols :)